# Equivalent of `aov` with `split` argument for contrasts in GLM in R

Tags: r, anova, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, contrasts

In case of linear models (LM) it is possible to get ANOVA with planned contrasts by using a contrast matrix and aov.

Is there any equivalent of the same for analysis of deviance in case of generealized linear models (GLM).

```
# Random data

n <- 128
cond <- gl(4, n/4, labels=c("A", "B", "C","Control"))
dose <- gl(4, 4, length=n, labels=c("None", "Low", "Med", "High"), ordered=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(cond=cond, dose=dose)
data$y <- ifelse(data$cond=="Control", rnorm(n, mean=100, sd=10), 
                 ifelse(data$cond=="A", rnorm(n, mean=110, sd=10),
                    rnorm(n, mean=120, sd=10)))
data$y <- ifelse(data$dose=="Low", data$y + 10, 
                 ifelse(data$dose=="Med", data$y + 15,
                        data$y))
```

#### LM without any planned contrasts

```
model1 <- lm(formula = y ~ cond * dose, data = data)
summary(model1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ cond * dose, data = data)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -23.621  -6.170   0.775   7.236  31.893 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)        121.8649     1.8622  65.440  < 2e-16 ***
#> condB                4.5345     2.6336   1.722   0.0879 .  
#> condC                5.3258     2.6336   2.022   0.0455 *  
#> condControl        -15.1902     2.6336  -5.768 7.23e-08 ***
#> dose.L               6.5723     3.7245   1.765   0.0804 .  
#> dose.Q             -16.9620     3.7245  -4.554 1.35e-05 ***
#> dose.C              -2.2083     3.7245  -0.593   0.5544    
#> condB:dose.L        -8.1583     5.2672  -1.549   0.1242    
#> condC:dose.L        -9.6395     5.2672  -1.830   0.0699 .  
#> condControl:dose.L  -2.8519     5.2672  -0.541   0.5893    
#> condB:dose.Q         7.8131     5.2672   1.483   0.1408    
#> condC:dose.Q         5.2753     5.2672   1.002   0.3187    
#> condControl:dose.Q   5.9814     5.2672   1.136   0.2585    
#> condB:dose.C        -0.3803     5.2672  -0.072   0.9426    
#> condC:dose.C         1.5393     5.2672   0.292   0.7706    
#> condControl:dose.C  -0.3962     5.2672  -0.075   0.9402    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 10.53 on 112 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.5376, Adjusted R-squared:  0.4757 
#> F-statistic: 8.682 on 15 and 112 DF,  p-value: 6.364e-13
```

#### LM with planned contrast

```
# Prepare contrast matrix (non-orthogonal)
AvB <- c(0, 1, -1, 0)
cmat <- cbind(AvB)
cmat
#>      AvB
#> [1,]   0
#> [2,]   1
#> [3,]  -1
#> [4,]   0

contrasts(data$cond) <- cmat

model2 <- lm( y ~ cond, data=data, contrasts=list(cond=cmat))
summary(model2)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ cond, data = data, contrasts = list(cond = cmat))
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -44.125  -9.190   0.537  10.496  28.735 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 120.5324     1.2908  93.378   <2e-16 ***
#> condAvB      -0.3956     1.8255  -0.217    0.829    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 14.6 on 126 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.0003727,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.007561 
#> F-statistic: 0.04697 on 1 and 126 DF,  p-value: 0.8288
```

Using `aov` for ANOVA

```
model2_aov <- aov(y ~ cond * dose, data=data)
summary(model2_aov)
#>              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#> cond          3   8722  2907.4  26.199 6.49e-13 ***
#> dose          3   4952  1650.8  14.876 3.23e-08 ***
#> cond:dose     9    778    86.5   0.779    0.636    
#> Residuals   112  12429   111.0                     
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

summary(model2_aov, split=list( cond=list(condAvB=1))) 
#>                       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#> cond                   3   8722  2907.4  26.199 6.49e-13 ***
#>   cond: condAvB        1     10    10.0   0.090    0.764    
#> dose                   3   4952  1650.8  14.876 3.23e-08 ***
#> cond:dose              9    778    86.5   0.779    0.636    
#>   cond:dose: condAvB   3     49    16.4   0.148    0.931    
#> Residuals            112  12429   111.0                     
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

#### GLM without any planned contrasts

```
model1_glm <- glm( y ~ cond * dose, data=data, 
                   family = gaussian("identity"))
summary(model1_glm)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = y ~ cond * dose, family = gaussian("identity"), 
#>     data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)        118.5571     2.1091  56.211  < 2e-16 ***
#> condB                4.7186     2.9828   1.582 0.116481    
#> condC                6.9665     2.9828   2.336 0.021293 *  
#> condControl        -13.1903     2.9828  -4.422 2.27e-05 ***
#> dose.L               3.8208     4.2183   0.906 0.367005    
#> dose.Q             -16.3653     4.2183  -3.880 0.000177 ***
#> dose.C               2.2530     4.2183   0.534 0.594328    
#> condB:dose.L        -1.3011     5.9655  -0.218 0.827740    
#> condC:dose.L        -3.4821     5.9655  -0.584 0.560588    
#> condControl:dose.L  -0.8778     5.9655  -0.147 0.883278    
#> condB:dose.Q        11.0729     5.9655   1.856 0.066060 .  
#> condC:dose.Q        -2.5442     5.9655  -0.426 0.670577    
#> condControl:dose.Q   3.0707     5.9655   0.515 0.607749    
#> condB:dose.C        -3.4766     5.9655  -0.583 0.561217    
#> condC:dose.C        -3.8945     5.9655  -0.653 0.515199    
#> condControl:dose.C  -6.3596     5.9655  -1.066 0.288691    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 142.3501)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 30846  on 127  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 15943  on 112  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 1014.8
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

#### GLM with planned contrasts?

```
model2_glm <- glm( y ~ cond * dose, data=data, contrasts=list(cond=cmat),
               family = gaussian("identity"))
summary(model2_glm)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = y ~ cond * dose, family = gaussian("identity"), 
#>     data = data, contrasts = list(cond = cmat))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)     118.181      1.249  94.600  < 2e-16 ***
#> condAvB          -1.124      1.767  -0.636   0.5259    
#> dose.L            2.405      2.498   0.963   0.3376    
#> dose.Q          -13.465      2.498  -5.389 3.59e-07 ***
#> dose.C           -1.180      2.498  -0.472   0.6377    
#> condAvB:dose.L    1.091      3.534   0.309   0.7581    
#> condAvB:dose.Q    6.809      3.534   1.927   0.0564 .  
#> condAvB:dose.C    0.209      3.534   0.059   0.9529    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 199.7662)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 30846  on 127  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 23972  on 120  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 1051
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```